# asp.net mvc 3 ajax form with in telrik Grid On Submits Opens a New Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, telerik-grid

in my ASP. Net MVC 3.0 Project.
I have Telerik Grid.

with in the grid cell I am loading content from partial view with a Ajax Form in it.
(for each Cell in one column of the grid)

when i submit that form.

Ajax form is opening new page instead of updating the target ID.

I am loading the required scripts

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These scripts are loaded on master page (_Layout.cshtml)

My Web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I have used the Ajax forms at most of the places in this project.
It works perfect at all those places.

Any clue if i can submit ajax form from a telerik grid

More Details

Controller

```
public JsonResult AddRemoveThisLocation(int LocationID, FormCollection collection, string button)
    {
return Json(new
        {
            success = _success,
            message = _message
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
 }
```

Partial View loaded in to the Telerik Grid using .loadContentfrom() method

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddRemoveThisLocation", "Controller", new { LocationID = Model.AddressID }, new AjaxOptions {
OnBegin="ValidateNumbers",
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnSuccess = "ShowSignUpStatus"} ))
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { id="phone"+Model.AddressID, name="Phone" })
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="button" name="button" id="@(Model.AddressID)" />
}
```

Comment: nothing no error or warning. on submit it hits the function and gets the result, Displays the result in a new page. instead of updating hte target Id with the result. I also notices on Ajax form i gave Onbegin="ValidateForm", On submit it is not hitting the ValidateForm Function also. Basically it is not hitting any ajax options I declare in Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: Can I see the controller action and your view Ajax code? Do you have [HttpPost] in your Controller action?

Comment: I have updated my quest with Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem. adn the solution is confirm no repeated jQuery References
and check if these are loadin correctly.

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public JsonResult AddRemoveThisLocation(int LocationID, FormCollection collection, string button)
        {
    return Json(new
            {
                success = _success,
                message = _message
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
     }
```

Comment: No difference. Firstly it is not firing the validate function i call OnBegin="ValidateNumbers" My Method (AddRemoveThisLocation) works perfect as needed and returns correct data. But the ajax options i gave in my view are not working.

Comment: what if you remove your options? Does it still open in new page?

Comment: Yes it does open in new page with the result